# Make a div stay in the same position compared to another div

Tags: html, css

I need my two white divs to stay in the exact same place compared to my black div in the middle. The should stay the exact same distance away from the black div when minimizing the page.

```css
#halvfjerds {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1050px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#halvfjerds .timeline {
  background-color: black;
}

#halvfjerds .linje1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 18vw;
  margin-top: 220px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

#halvfjerds .linje2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 54vw;
  margin-top: 780px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.timeline {
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1.4%
}
```

```html
<div id="halvfjerds">
  <div class="timeline">
  </div>
  <div class="linje1">
  </div>
  <div class="linje2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope someone out there can help!

Comment: did you mean horizontal or vertical ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pb76pb4c/ heres a fiddle that hopefully explains it better. The white div doesnt behave the way it should @Huelfe

Answer (score 1):

```
#halvfjerds .timeline {
background-color:black;
position: relative;
}
```

I don't know if that is what you need, if it's don't just let me know

Comment: make it full screen. You can see that the white div doesnt behave the way it should

Comment: @AdrianKirkegaard then I don't really get what you want to do, using `relative` method should make the divs with `position: absolute;` moving relative to the div you choosed relative

Comment: MY wto smaller divs has to move relative to the laarger div in the middle. when i adjust the windows' size, they should still stay in the same position relative to the black div in the middle.

Comment: @AdrianKirkegaard First set `position` of the parent DIV to `relative` (specifying the offset, i.e. `left`, `top` etc. is not necessary) and then apply `position: absolute` to the child DIV with the offset you want.  
It's simple and should do the trick well. (That's what i found in doc)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the same `margin-left: 18vw;`

If not like this solution, so I don't understand

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to give position:absolute style property to divs.

Comment: what div should i give Pos:absolute?